# Binding values to form fields in batman.js and Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, forms, data-binding, batman.js

I'm building an app using batman.js and rails 3.2.

I would like to automatically populate this form with the current_user's id as well as the message_thread's id that this message will be added into.

```
<form data-formfor-message="controllers.messages.newMessage" data-event-submit="controllers.messages.create">
    <input class="new-item" placeholder="type here..." data-bind="message.body" />
    <input class="new-item" type="hidden" data-bind="message.message_thread_id" />
    <input class="new-item" type="hidden" data-bind="message.user_id" />
    <input type="submit" value="Reply" />
</form>
```

I've looked around for a while but haven't found anything yet. If you need more information to answer my question please ask.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found there is the `data-bind-value` method.

```
<form data-formfor-message="controllers.messages.newMessage" data-event-submit="controllers.messages.create">
    <input placeholder="type here..." data-bind="message.body" />
    <input data-bind-value="message_thread.id" type="hidden" data-bind="message.message_thread_id" />
    <input data-bind-valude="currentUser.id" type="hidden" data-bind="message.user_id" />
    <input type="submit" value="Reply" />
</form>
```

That does the trick.